# Printing a text file on website hosted on raspberry pi

Tags: html, server, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry Pi hosting a local website (not connected to Internet - doesn't need to be).

When users access the webpage held on the pi, I would like for the web page to start printing line by line from a large text file.

eg: text files contains

```
Hello
 How are 
 You doing
 Today?
```

Browser will print above line by line with delay

Should be trying this directly with HTML or maybe Javascript - I have very little experience in both.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with print line by line? Do you mean that each line has to be shown with a delay?

Comment: hey @t.niese op updated with clarificaiton

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript in that webpage (served by a webserver) to load the text file and print content line by line. The text file should be directly accessible from the webserver for javascript to be able to read it directly.

Comment: That is one potential way to do it, yes.

Comment: You can also extend it with more sophisticated ways where a separate module keeps pushing data with websockets as soon as page loads.

Comment: Or, y'know, stand up a real web server like Apache.

Comment: Thanks for link @RobertHarvey already have site set up using hostapd dnsmasq nginx

Comment: That would have been nice to know up front.